# I would like to control existing database under liquibase in Corda. I am using liquibase of xml format

Tags: blockchain, liquibase, corda

I tried using "create table" changelog, but I got an error - "There is an existing table". Can anyone help how could be the liquibase xml file to control my existing database using liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this documentation: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-database.html#node-database?

Check [this](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/node/operating/node-database.html#database-management-tool-ref) out for Enterprise Corda.

Comment: I am using Corda Enterprise. I would like to sync the liquibase with my existing MSSQL database.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "sync"? Can you provide an example of the current status of your DB and what you are trying to achieve? 

I added the link to DB management for Corda Enterprise in my answer. Did you check that out already?

Comment: I am using mssql database. In that database, there is some existing data. I could implement liquibase on empty database and create the tables successfully. But, in the database with existing data, I am facing an issue. Hope you understood my problem.